# Alert Dialog Dialog Builder setView crops the top layout when height of dialog is maximum i.e. stretched to the screen - Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, dialog, android-alertdialog

I have created an alert dialog and use setView.
The layout height is set to `wrap_content`

When text in dialog is enough to fill the screen, dialog crops the top view.

**Normal Text:**
[image]

**Large Text:**
[image]

**XML of the dialog layout:**

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_close"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:src="@drawable/close"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="@color/text_color_dark"
    android:text="Heading/Title i.e. Lorem Ipsum"/>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:scrollbars="none">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color_dark"
            android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummysoftware like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum dummysoftware like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum dummysoftware like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum dummysoftware like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum dummysoftware like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum dummysoftware like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum dummysoftware like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum dummysoftware like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum dummysoftware like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum ."/>
        <uk.org.humanfocus.hfi.CustomViews.ButtonColorDark
            android:id="@+id/btn_ok"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minWidth="100dp"
            android:minHeight="30dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Ok"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**Java Code of Dialog:**

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.AppDialogTheme));
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        View dialog = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_display_information, null);
        dialogBuilder.setView(dialog);
        dialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
        final AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();

        alertDialog.show();

        ((TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_title)).setText(title);
        ((TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_text)).setText(text);

        dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_ok).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                alertDialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        dialog.findViewById(R.id.iv_close).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                alertDialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        return alertDialog;
```

Comment: I tested this and it seems to work without any issues. could you tell AppDialogTheme style and the android version you tested this on?

Comment: @Ramin Theme is android:Theme.Holo.Light and I am testing it on Android 6.0

Comment: I used Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar and the support.v7 AlertDialog, testing in android 6 emulator and android 4.4 phone. both work as expected without cropping anything.

Comment: Where can I go wrong :/

Comment: @Ramin I am using it in a full screen activity. Please try this.

Comment: tried everything, fullscreen, AppCompat and non Compat theme and alertdialog. I suspect whatever is wrong with your dialog is probably in the styles. try to play around with them, both the alertDialog and Activities. also see if you find anything with when you call show. because the Dialog seems completely ok as far as copy pasting and testing your code in a blank activity goes.